# Are parens '()' required for a no-argument constructor call?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any difference between the following two code samples?

```
var label:Label = new Label;

var label:Label = new Label();
```

I ask because some tutorials on the net warn to always use '()'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference, it absolutely the same, but using parents are more common for AS3 coding style.

Answer (score 3):

When a new object is created, i.e. with a `new`, then there is no difference. So, `new MyClassWithNoArgument` and `new MyClassWithNoArgument()` are same.

However, in general `aMethod` and `aMethod()` are not same. `aMethod` is a `Function` object, and using parentheses on a function object calls that.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of **empty constructor** (like most of the objects in the display list such as `DisplayObject`, `Sprite`, `MovieClip` etc) there is absolutely no difference

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference on constructors that can accept zero arguments when used with the new operator.  Even though the parentheses '()' are implicitly added, you should use them for consistency / clarity that you intented to call function instead of pass a reference of the function.